# QGIS crashes when I try to check for double or check for crossing lines

Tags: qgis, topology

I have a LineString layer that I want to check for double geometries and/or intersecting lines. I've tried two different tools (Check Geometry (Geometryprüfung) and Check Topology (Topologyprüfung)) and they both crash with my layer and I have no idea why.

```
Crash resport:
Crash ID: 12b1bee7ec347015efdb44f06b72d8dacdfe3999    

Stack Trace    

Index::~Index :
Index::~Index :
Index::~Index :
QgsSpatialIndex::addFeature qgsspatialindex.cpp:453
QgsSpatialIndex::addFeature qgsspatialindex.cpp:410
QgsFeaturePool::insertFeature qgsfeaturepool.cpp:126
QgsVectorDataProviderFeaturePool::QgsVectorDataProviderFeaturePool qgsvectordataproviderfeaturepool.cpp:41
QgsGeometryCheckerSetupTab::runChecks qgsgeometrycheckersetuptab.cpp:445
QMetaObject::activate :
QAbstractButton::clicked :
QAbstractButton::click :
QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent :
QWidget::event :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:458
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:458
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
UserCallWinProcCheckWow :
DispatchMessageWorker :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main main.cpp:1637
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :
       
QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.16.5-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 58ba7c1ed6
Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2
Running against Qt: 5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL: 3.1.4
Running against GDAL: 3.1.4

System Info
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.18363
```

I've also tried on two different machines, exported the layer and projected it but nothing helped.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: What are the two different tools you used?

Comment: Check Geometry (Geometrieprüfung) and check topology (Topologieprüfung). For both tools other checks work just fine. But double crashes everytime.

Comment: Can you also add what type of vector layer this is?  Shapefile, Postgres, etc.  Here is a potential tutorial on a third method you can try.  https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/handling_invalid_geometries.html.  Skip ahead to the check validity part.

Comment: It is a feature layer with lines saved as a geopackage. I'm still pretty new to GIS. What is Postgres?

Comment: Is the issue that you have null geometries in the geopackage?  Here is a tutorial for fixing invalid geometries for a geopackage.  https://kartoza.com/en/blog/debugging-digitizing-errors-from-google-earth-layer-in-qgis/   PostGIS is a GIS extension of the PostGres database.  So, Postgres can be used to store GIS data for visualization and manipulation, like Shapefiles or a geopackage.